# Comparing files by their hash, but I need the names not just the hashes

Tags: powershell, compare

I am trying to compare files and directories by hash, and it is working, but I now need an easier way to figure out which file is in different.

I originally started without comparing the hash, and it worked for files and folders, but it would not tell me anything other than the fact that they exist.

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem -recurse –Path E:\path | foreach  {Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName}
$Destination = Get-ChildItem -recurse –Path "\\server\e$\path" | foreach  {Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source.hash  -DifferenceObject $Destination.hash
```

Now this works great, but I want to also list the files that are associated with the hash.  After I get the hash, I then need to go back to the files and compare the hash to the original directories to figure out which one it came from.

```
InputObject                                                      SideIndicator
-----------                                                      -------------
CFD1DF3C08A9F7C4D81E22DA7D1CBB35FA12220C3CB85777EBA9BD89362AEDA3 =>           
2B098B7FC189A87B41A7706EA7ABFFDB343B8B5AF3712BA6614E04BD3032A977 =>           
D8CBDD03564C3547D8189D11A9BAE078FBD70986DBFB485EAEE5170C13113798 =>           
F5D7AE29DB432EC3421EE956B70927AE394C0F27CE00FF855666DBC3E14084DB <=           
85795253C6CCDC3CC2A4CAE055CC7478946CDB33D35EAE2BB5796C55954205B2 <=           
9CE2A42C8FFA2D8001BA2874324987DCEF601173CB2ED8B654A76598F90B126E <=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are going for the hash why not use the Group-Object instead of the Compare-Object. Something like this:

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem -recurse –Path E:\path
$Destination = Get-ChildItem -recurse –Path "\\server\e$\path"
$Source + $Destination | Group-Object @{Expression={(Get-FileHash $_.FullName).hash}} | ? {$_.Count -gt 1}
```

Output would be something like this:

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                       
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                       
    2 DF7E70E5021544F4834BBE... {b.txt, c.txt}
```

Comment: That does group them, but I am looking at thousands of files, and only want the files that are different.  If I do it your way, I can change it to say  
    {$_.Count -lt 2}  it seems to only show the files that are different.     Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compare-Object by default outputs differences,
if you want to compare Hash **and** Name (without path)
there is the problem that `Get-FileHash` only output's `Algorithm`,`Hash` and the complete `Path`.

You can directly pipe `Get-ChildItem` output to `Get-FileHash`,
but need to attach the Name (here using a calculated property)

I'd use the `-PassThru` parameter and use the whole objects specifying the properties `Hash` and `Name` for comparison.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\12\SO_565666700.ps1
$SourceDir = 'E:\path'          # 'C:\Bat' # 
$TargetDir = '\\server\e$\path' # 'K:\Bat' # 

$Source = Get-ChildItem –Path $SourceDir -Recurse -PipeLineVar Item |
    Get-FileHash | Select-Object *,@{n='Name';e={$Item.Name}}
$Target = Get-ChildItem –Path $TargetDir -Recurse -PipeLineVar Item |
    Get-FileHash | Select-Object *,@{n='Name';e={$Item.Name}}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $Source -Property Name,Hash `
               -DifferenceObject $Target -PassThru |
    Sort-Object Name | Select-Object Hash,Path
```